# Retornar dados de outro component

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

Tenho o seguinte problema, crio o usuário e adiciono o mesmo em um curso.
Só que não consigo retornar o nome do curso na página do usuário. O curso é adicionado via select input, enviando apenas o ID do mesmo. Quando dou o  retorno via

```
{{user.curso}}
```

Ele retorna _id: "5b38e3bc9dbf9113560a2d4c".

Tentei criar um pipe e filtrar pelo usuario.curso, mas também não funcionou. Não retornou nenhuma informação.

```js
@Pipe({
    name: "filter",
    pure: false
})
export class ArrayFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
 
    transform(items: Array<any>, conditions: {[field: string]: any}): Array<any> {
        return items.filter(item => {
            for (let field in conditions) {
                if (item[field] !== conditions[field]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
}

<div class="content" *ngFor="let curso of cursos | filter:{user:user.curso}">
<li>{{curso.title}}</li>
  </div>
```

Alguém pode me dá uma dica?

Comment: Tem como postar o codigo do seu select? Pela sua pergunta vc esta usando um div invés de um select.

Comment: Conseguir resolver e da maneira correta trabalhando no backend, usei aggegate com $lookup e consegui resolver.